# WooCommerce AJAX Add to Cart for Variable products, still redirecting to product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Previously, after adding a product to cart from archive page, the page stays on the same page (not redirecting), but this only works for a simple product. What I'm trying to do is enable this feature for the variable product also (display product options at archive page without having to go to product page first).

Based on this link:

[[WooCommerce 3.0+] Ajax add to cart on variable products archive page](https://gist.github.com/rynaldos/ae17fcdb74bd304cfb64dc8692208b2d)

Using this code:

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

   if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' ) ) {

        function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
             global $product;

             if ($product->get_type() == "variable" ) {
                 woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
             }
             else {
                 wc_get_template( 'loop/add-to-cart.php' );
             }
         }
    }

    function ajax_add_to_cart_script() {

      wp_enqueue_script( 'add-to-cart-variation', plugins_url() . '/woocommerce-ajax-add-to-cart-variable-products/js/add-to-cart-variation.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
      wp_localize_script( 'add-to-cart-variation', 'AddToCartAjax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),

      ));
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_add_to_cart_script' );

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_add_to_cart_variable_rc', 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_variable_rc_callback' );

    function woocommerce_add_to_cart_variable_rc_callback() {
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_POST['product_id'] ) );
        $quantity = empty( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', $_POST['quantity'] );
        $variation_id = $_POST['variation_id'];
        $variation  = $_POST['variation'];
        $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );

        if ( $passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation  ) ) {
            do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id );
            if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message( $product_id );
        }

        $this->get_refreshed_fragments();
        } else {
            $this->json_headers();

        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id )
            );
        echo json_encode( $data );
        }
        die();
    }  
}
```

I'm half-way there, but the biggest problem now is after adding a variable product AND/OR a simple product to cart, I'm being redirected to the product page (the product is added to cart just fine).

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I found the difference in HTML before and after adding the code above is this:

Before:

```
<a href="/product-category/meats/?instock_products=in&#038;v=b718adec73e0&#038;add-to-cart=861" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="861" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add &ldquo;Whole Pork Fillet (400G Up) Chilled&rdquo; to your cart" rel="nofollow">
```

After:

```
<a href="/product-category/meats/?instock_products=in&#038;v=b718adec73e0&#038;add-to-cart=861" data-quantity="1" class="button" >
```

Not sure though if that's the main cause. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Does it help if you click the "Redirect to the cart page after successful addition" checkbox?

[image: It is found in Woocommerce > Settings > Products]

It is found in Woocommerce > Settings > Products

Comment: Hi, I've tried that, not working.. I've found a link on SO that includes some custom AJAX for this, using prevent default etc. But I forgot to bookmark it, and now I can't find it anymore ugh..